# ImageCreateTrueColor behaves differently on different machines

Tags: php, gd

I have two different machines, one with Ubuntu9.3 PHP - 5.3.3 and other Ubuntu9.3 PHP 5.3.5.

Both in PHP 5.3.3 and PHP 5.3.5 has same code.

```
<?php
  header ("Content-type: image/png");
  $handle = ImageCreateTrueColor (700, 420) or die ("Cannot Create image");
  $bg_color = ImageColorAllocate ($handle, 251,248, 255);
  imagefill ( $handle, 0, 0, $bg_color );
  ImagePng ($handle);
 ?>
```

PHP 5.3.3 gives me "Black" color

while, PHP 5.3.5 results "light blue" (Expected Output)

Also, if I replace my function from ImageCreateTrueColor to ImageCreate, i get "Light blue" in both machines.

Please help me, I know there is something to do with ImageCreateTrueColor?

I have GD2 version in both machines.

Comment: These functions depend on GD library. If GD versiions are different, the results might differ too.

Comment: I have GD2 in both machines, how do i check GD Version 2 with Revision number?

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and scroll down to the `gd` section.

Comment: Dan - This gives same results for both.

Comment: [Changelog for PHP](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) indicates many changes in 5.3.4 including one to GD. May or may not be related. Why is it surprising that different versions produce different results?

Comment: 2.0.28 or later? I have no ideas except to specify the alpha value in your color as well.

Comment: I did a diff between all lib's For PHP 5.3.5 < **php5-gd/maverick uptodate 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5** , while For PHP 5.3.3 **php5-gd/maverick upgradeable from 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 to 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5**

Answer (score 0):

The new versions of GD have had significant updates. Even a subversion difference (e.g. 2.2 vs 2.3) can result in different output. You can try updating your gd library by downloading the library from here: https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/downloads. You will also need a php wrapper for the library.